# Open ExtJS app in Outlook - Outlook imitates IE7?

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs, outlook

I have a Web App that should integrate with Outlook 2013, and hopefully also with Outlook 2010.

In Outlook, you can have a folder with a "Default Web Site", which is used for all kind of fun at our customer's.

But not with our app, because - only in Outlook - an error is thrown deep in Ext code, at

```
if (Ext.isIE9m) {
    Element.prototype.getById = function (id, asDom) {
        var dom = this.dom,
            cacheItem, el, ret;

        if (dom) {
            // for normal elements getElementById is the best solution, but if the el is
            // not part of the document.body, we need to use all[]
            el = (useDocForId && DOC.getElementById(id)) || dom.all[id];
```

in the last line, it says

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'ext-quicktips-tip-frame1MC' of undefined or null reference

Everything works well in IE11, IE10, IE9, IE8, FF24, FF37, Chrome 37, since I use `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">`. But this does not help with Outlook, which tells me it is

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64, Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Microsoft Outlook 15.0.4615)

Can I tell Outlook to use the most recent IE installed - and to set the user agent accordingly?

Is Outlook using IE7 (or IE7 render mode), or is it just submitting a plain wrong user agent, and ExtJS falls into the pit by wrongly assuming that every browser passing the Ext.isIE9m test has a specific features available?

Comment: I am facing same error. Did u get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The InternetExplorer has the javascript object `document.documentMode` which is set correctly, but ExtJS does not evaluate it correctly.

So it works if Ext-more.js contains the following:

```
isIE7 = isIE && ((check(/msie 7/) && docMode != 8 && docMode != 9 && docMode != 10 && docMode != 11) || docMode == 7),
isIE8 = isIE && ((check(/msie 8/) && docMode != 7 && docMode != 9 && docMode != 10 && docMode != 11) || docMode == 8),
isIE9 = isIE && ((check(/msie 9/) && docMode != 7 && docMode != 8 && docMode != 10 && docMode != 11) || docMode == 9),
isIE10 = isIE && ((check(/msie 10/) && docMode != 7 && docMode != 8 && docMode != 9 && docMode != 11) || docMode == 10),
isIE11 = isIE && ((check(/trident\/7\.0/) && docMode != 7 && docMode != 8 && docMode != 9 && docMode != 10) || docMode == 11),
```

instead of

```
isIE7 = isIE && ((check(/msie 7/) && docMode != 8 && docMode != 9 && docMode != 10) || docMode == 7),
isIE8 = isIE && ((check(/msie 8/) && docMode != 7 && docMode != 9 && docMode != 10) || docMode == 8),
isIE9 = isIE && ((check(/msie 9/) && docMode != 7 && docMode != 8 && docMode != 10) || docMode == 9),
isIE10 = isIE && ((check(/msie 10/) && docMode != 7 && docMode != 8 && docMode != 9) || docMode == 10),
isIE11 = isIE && ((check(/trident\/7\.0/) && docMode != 7 && docMode != 8 && docMode != 9 && docMode != 10) || docMode == 11),
```